# Bracket expected.... not sure where

Tags: java, debugging

So I'm doing an assignment on modular programing and here Im getting a bracket expected error. Here is the code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class stlab09
{       

public static void main (String args[])                             
{   
    System.out.println("\nLAB09 90 POINT VERSION\n\n");
    enterData();
    computeGPA();
    displayData();
}

static String lGrade1;
static String lGrade2;
static String lGrade3;
static String lGrade4;
static int cHours1; 
static int cHours2;
static int cHours3;
static int cHours4;
static String dummy;
public static double gpa;

public static void enterData()
{       
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);    
    System.out.print("Enter course 1 Grade  ===>>  ");
    lGrade1 = in.nextLine();
    System.out.print("enter course 1 Hours  ===>>  ");
    cHours1 = in.nextInt(); dummy = in.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter course 2 Grade  ===>>  ");
    lGrade2 = in.nextLine(); 
    System.out.print("enter course 2 Hours  ===>>  ");
    cHours2 = in.nextInt(); dummy = in.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter course 3 Grade  ===>>  ");
    lGrade3 = in.nextLine(); 
    System.out.print("enter course 3 Hours  ===>>  ");
    cHours3 = in.nextInt(); dummy = in.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter course 4 Grade  ===>>  ");
    lGrade4 = in.nextLine(); 
    System.out.print("enter course 4 Hours  ===>>  ");
    cHours4 = in.nextInt(); dummy = in.nextLine();
}

public static void computeGPA()
{
    Grades.gradeValue();
    Grades.courseValue();
    Grades.getGPA();
}

public static void displayData()
{   
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Course1 Grade: " + lGrade1 +  "  Course1 Credit Hours: " + cHours1);
    System.out.println("Course2 Grade: " + lGrade2 +  "  Course2 Credit Hours: " + cHours2);
    System.out.println("Course3 Grade: " + lGrade3 +  "  Course3 Credit Hours: " + cHours3);
    System.out.println("Course4 Grade: " + lGrade4 +  "  Course4 Credit Hours: " + cHours4);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Current GPA: " + gpa);
}
}

public class Grades() ***<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< bracket expected here***
{
public static void gradeValue()
{
    int value = 0;

    char lg1 = lGrade1.charAt(0);
    switch(lg1)
        {
            case 'A':  value = 4;  break;
            case 'B':  value = 3;  break;
            case 'C':  value = 2;  break;
            case 'D':  value = 1;  break;
            case 'F':  value = 0;  break;
        }

    int gVal1 = value;

    char lg2 = lGrade2.charAt(0);
    switch(lg2)
        {
            case 'A':  value = 4;  break;
            case 'B':  value = 3;  break;
            case 'C':  value = 2;  break;
            case 'D':  value = 1;  break;
            case 'F':  value = 0;  break;
        }

    int gVal2 = value;

    char lg3 = lGrade3.charAt(0);
    switch(lg3)
        {
            case 'A':  value = 4;  break;
            case 'B':  value = 3;  break;
            case 'C':  value = 2;  break;
            case 'D':  value = 1;  break;
            case 'F':  value = 0;  break;
        }

    int gVal3 = value;

    char lg4 = lGrade4.charAt(0);
    switch(lg4)
        {
            case 'A':  value = 4;  break;
            case 'B':  value = 3;  break;
            case 'C':  value = 2;  break;
            case 'D':  value = 1;  break;
            case 'F':  value = 0;  break;
        }
    int gVal4 = value; 
}

public static void courseValue()
{ 
    int cVal1 = gVal1 * cHours1;
    int cVal2 = gVal2 * cHours2;
    int cVal3 = gVal3 * cHours3;
    int cVal4 = gVal4 * cHours4;
}

public static void getGPA()
{
    double totalValue = cVal1 + cVal2 + cVal3 + cVal4;
    double totalHours = cHours1 + cHours2 + cHours3 + cHours4;
    double gpa = totalValue / totalHours;
}
}
```

So yeah I need some help figuring this out because I'm kinda going crazy about it. The expected program is supposed to use keyboard input of letter grades and course hours to compute GPA and grades. The assignment is to get that outcome but the main method must stay exactly as is, and almost every method was provided to me and i just had to organize them.

Comment: To blurt it out: `displayData()` shouldn't have two closing braces, and its just `public class Grades` no parenthesis required.

Comment: NM my comment, failed to `ASSERT(Java == C);` :(

Comment: @Quirliom The second brace is for the class that it's in, not for `displayData()` (yes, I agree that the indentation should be better). There's a similar thing going on with `getGPA()` and the `Grades` class.

Comment: @Quirliom Not a problem. I do it too from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared the inner class `Grades` as if it's a method (you added `()` onto the end of it), look at how the class `stlab09` is declared, there aren't any `()`.

Comment: As Dennis Meng pointed out in response to my comment on the question, the extra brace after displayData() is to end the class, therefore should be there.